# Maven not adding Jar reference using read-project-properties

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm referencing a jar file which is stored in my local machine with the help of properties-maven-plugin. I'm doing this so that on jenkins I can define a separate path through properties file. When I add following code to POM it does not bring the jar, therefore, code can't reference it. Any suggestions ?

```
<build>
    (...)
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>src/main/resources/app.properties</file>
                        </files>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.company.tibco.mqm</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <scope>system</scope>
                                <systemPath>${ibm.mq.jar}</systemPath>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    (...)
    </plugins>
</build>
```

app.properties file is as following

```
ibm.mq.jar=C:\setup\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why not defining the dependency via usual dependency ?

Comment: I'm reading path of the jar from a properties file. I'm doing this so that on jenkins we have separate path and on local developers machine we can have our own path. We are not allowed to have this jar in our repository server, therefore we had to go this route